# How can I get a stateful LSTM to reset its states between epochs during a Keras Tuner search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras-tuner, lstm-stateful

I am trying to tune a stateful LSTM using Keras Tuner. I have the code working and it is able to train models, but I still can't figure out how to get the model to reset states between epochs. Normally I would train for 1 epoch at a time in a loop and manually reset_states between epochs. However, I do not believe this is even possible for Keras Tuner. Is there an argument I can use that would accomplish this? This is my current tuner code below:

```
def build_model(hp):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Input(batch_shape=(batch_size,train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2])))
    for i in range(hp.Int('num_LSTM_layers', 1, 3)):
        model.add(layers.LSTM(units=hp.Int('units_' + str(i),min_value=32,max_value=512,step=4),
                    batch_input_shape=(batch_size,train_X.shape[1], train_X.shape[2]),
                         activation=hp.Choice('LSTM_activation_' + str(i),values=['relu','softplus',
                                                                 'tanh', 'sigmoid','softsign','selu','elu','linear'],
                    default='elu'),return_sequences=True,stateful=True))
    for j in range(hp.Int('num_dense_layers', 1, 3)):
        model.add(layers.Dense(units=hp.Int('units_' + str(i),min_value=64,max_value=1024,step=4),
                         activation=hp.Choice('dense_activation_' + str(i),values=['relu','softplus',
                                                                 'tanh', 'sigmoid','softsign','selu','elu','linear'],
                    default='elu')))
        model.add(layers.Dropout(rate=hp.Float('rate_' + str(i), min_value=0.01, max_value=0.50, step=0.01)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(train_y.shape[1],activation='linear'))
    model.compile(
            optimizer=hp.Choice('optimizers',values=['rmsprop','adam','adadelta','Nadam']),
            loss='mse',metrics=['mse'])
    return model

tuner_bo = BayesianOptimization(
            build_model,
            objective='val_loss',
            max_trials=50,
            executions_per_trial=3,overwrite=True,num_initial_points=10,
            directory=model_path,project_name='LSTM_KT_2001',
            allow_new_entries=True,tune_new_entries=True)

tuner_bo.search_space_summary()

tuner_bo.search(train_X, train_y, epochs=100,batch_size=1,validation_data=(test_X,test_y), verbose=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

I overrode the on_epoch_end method in tuner class, Not sure whether the approach is correct or not.

```
class MyBayesianOptimization(BayesianOptimization):
    def on_epoch_end(self, trial, my_hyper_model, epoch, logs=None):
        my_hyper_model.reset_states()
        super(MyBayesianOptimization, self).on_epoch_end(trial, my_hyper_model, epoch, logs)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this somewhat old question! I will give this a shot and accept if it works.